# ScrollPane for Canvas on which i draw more than the size of the canvas

Tags: java, image, canvas, scroll

sorry if the title of the question is not that good, but here's the question: I'm making an image editor and I draw the image on a canvas. But the image might be larger than the size of the canvas, so i want to add some kind of scroll bars to scroll the image so i have access to all parts of image. how can i achieve this?

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your are working with Swing: make your canvas as large as the image, wrap it in a javax.swing.JScrollPane and add the scrollpane to the container instead of the canvas itself.

Then Swing will take care of everything: decorating the canvas with scrollbars, show another part of the canvas if the user scrolls the image or resizes the container etc.

If you are working with AWT use java.awt.ScrollPane instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the image is cropped to the size of the JScrollPane. and if the canvas is smaller than the JScrollPane, I can still draw outside the canvas.but when i use the scrollbars it scrolls among the cavas correctly. help?

Comment: nevermind, used ScrollPane instead of JScrollPane and worked. thanks for the answer